# Wordpress Database - Migrate From Staging to Production

Tags: database, wordpress, migration, relative-path

The wordpress database includes the full path to my url in many places  (e.g.  http://staging.mysite.com).

Every answer I've come across indicates that one should find and replace staging.mysite.com with mysite.com, or vise versa, every time I sync databases.

Is it okay to replace the full domain with '/' and alleviate the need to change database names back and forth?

Image paths should be fine.  But is there any reason to believe guid would be a problem?

Comment: interesting q...sure try it?

Comment: Seems to work fine...